# Unable to pair again bluetooth headset

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I used to have a this bluetooth (BT) headset paired and working. Because it had some audio stuttering issues, as a troubleshooting measure I decided to un-pair (remove from list of BT devices in Mac OS) and pair again.

The problem is that now the headset is not seen anymore. I have the headset in pairing mode and the BT preferences window open and there's no way it'll show. Other BT devices show, and I can pair the BT headset with other devices.

Using Mac OS 10.10.4.

How to pair the headset again? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes just restarting your Mac will do the trick.

Comment: Open and turn on BT on your Mac. It should be continuously scanning (small turning wheel). Turn o head set and put it in paring mode (usually holding the on/off for few seconds. You Mac should detect it now and offer you to pair it.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Unfortunately none of that helps - the only way to pair is doing what Buscar웃SD explained, so I've tried that many times, to no avail. I already restarted the Mac multiple times, the update from 10.10.3 to 10.10.4 didn't help. I reseted the PRAM & SMC too. No luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this idea: maybe it's the headset that is preventing the pairing from happening (remember I removed the pairing on the Mac, but on the headset it might still be somehow locked with the previous pairing for this specific device). When I read the manual a while ago I remember there was a way to clear the pairing settings.

So I did that, and voilá!, I can now pair with the Mac again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by deleting paired devices from

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

Edit with TextMate `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` like this:

Line with `PairedDevices = ( "00-00-00-XX-XX-XX" )`; change to `PairedDevices = ( )`; (X can be any letter or number).